# handling a large set of text data

Tags: android

I have this android application which is basically an app that summarizes the 10th grade physics book, it has four units, each unit has multiple subjects, i want to to display large set of text data which lets the user to scroll down the page when a user presses on a subject, how can i store these static data on the application?, and what method to use?, should i use fragments to display the content?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

**Each unit has many subjects like this, i want to display a large set of text when a user click on something**

Comment: Have you tried reading the official android documentation on these subjects first?

Comment: yes, i couldn't figure it out, some suggested that i should use SQLite,  but i want to know if there is another way

Comment: you can store the info in a file on the device or  you can download the text from the internet - your question is too broad. go with whatever you're most familiar with/willing to learn

Comment: Use Sqlite for store data offline if your application receive data from online

Comment: @Ashish No it doesn't, the data stored is static, it won't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i store these static data on the application?

To store the content you may use the SQLite database. The [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) from Jetpack is a good way to start. It's an SQLite wrapper which is very easy to learn and much easy to use. [This article](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) will teach you about basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) operation using Room.

> should i use fragments to display the content?

It's up to the application requirement. One use case would be, when you have a common navigation bar, fragment would be a better option. You can find more case  information on 'When to use fragments' from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8597908/4370279).

**@AJW**

> What if I already have a working SQLite database with a lot of custom
>   CRUD queries. And the queries use Cursors. Should I convert all of the
>   existing queries and replace them with new Room queries?

I haven't tried a complete migration yet, and not have too much experience with room. I tried some sample CRUD operations and it looks cool. It avoids so many boilerplate code that I used to write when using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, also it supports [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) , which is another big advantage, helps you to get database updates automatically. Altogether, `Room` looks promising, and I believe it's the future. I would suggest you to do a sample project before converting all your sqlite queries to `Room`. This [tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-livedata-and-viewmodel-fca5da39e26b) might help you to get started also the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) are pretty good.

> can I use the SQLite queries with Room?

Yes you can. Actually, `Room` needs the query to generate objects for us.

A typical `SELECT` query looks like below

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users")
fun loadAllUsers(): List<User>
```

You can find more examples from the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer really helped me clear my head.

Comment: @theapache64 What if I already have a working SQLite database with a lot of custom CRUD queries.  And the queries use Cursors.  Should I convert all of the existing queries and replace them with new Room queries?  Or can I use the SQLite queries with Room?

Comment: @AJW As the answer for you question became lengthy, I've added the reply on answer. Please check the updated answer.