# Does using the fragments lower down the load on main activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have created an Activity , but when i run it , the log says , X frames skipped, may be main activity doing too much work.

So using fragments for different parts, a good idea or not?

Comment: The question is too broad. Add more information like specifications and make it explicit.

Comment: Maybe don't do too much work on the main thread??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments are really useful. If you think about it, they are really two activities working together as one cohesive "unit".

**Advantages:**

- They are really versatile and give you the ability to make different types of apps and UI.
- Really easy to implement and low on memory.
- Reusability and portability

**Disadvantages:**

- More code(For example, instantiating a fragment manager, adding the fragment transaction, writing the callbacks of the fragment)
- Communication between fragments and activities is harder. You would need to deal with a parcelable interface to serialize your objects you wish to pass.

Now your question is too ***broad*** to give a meaningful answer, but if you are interested check these links out:

- [When and why should I use fragments in Android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597769/when-and-why-should-i-use-fragments-in-android-applications)
- [Dilemma: when to use Fragments vs Activities:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306091/dilemma-when-to-use-fragments-vs-activities)