# Why should I take advantage to this design?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, design-patterns, material-design

What I use `fragments` or `views`?

[image]

Comment: There is no need to use fragments in here, you just need to use multiple reyclerviews

Comment: Hi. how use container recyclerview?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please understand this isn't a free coding service or a forum, we only deal with specific, code related questions here. asking for advice or not showing any effort done won't get you much help. please do some research and try something first before asking here

Comment: @NovruzCeferov I think you need to use multiple RecyclerViews with horizontal Orientation which are nested inside one parent ScrollView.

Comment: Hey @NovruzCeferov welcome to stackoverflow, here we can help you with problems you are facing and help you solve it, we can't not tell you or give you everything. also read this [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think it's better if you could use a single recyclerview populating different viewtypes, so as to ensure better scrolling in contrast with scrollview with different recyclerviews.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RecyclerView with `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` for a Section.
If your Sections are variables then you should use nested RecyclerView where the parent RecyclerView will be `LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL` & Childs will be `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`

Have look on [this](https://github.com/malikmotani/NestedRecyclerView-Master)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs. You can go with @Afsar's answer If you won't use the same lists in somewhere else.

If you found yourself in a situation that you need to use any list of them in other activity you can implement it as a fragment to be reusable without duplicating the logic.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18841025/2968988) to know more about the benefits and drawbacks of using fragments.